# LOCK error after creating a clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I just created a clustered index on a 1MM row table (page and row locking turned on). I now try to run queries and I get this error:

> "The instance of the SQL Server Database Engine cannot obtain a LOCK
>   resource at this time. Rerun your statement when there are fewer
>   active users. Ask the database administrator to check the lock and
>   memory configuration for this instance, or to check for long-running
>   transactions."

I will need to adjust the page/ row locking settings later, but in the meantime I need to drop the index because I have users querying the table. I tried to drop it, but I received the same error. Any recommendations to drop the index for good? Thank you.

EDIT 1:
Based on Remus answer below, I ran the following script to enable dynamic allocation of memory for locks.

```
EXEC sp_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1 RECONFIGURE
EXEC sp_configure 'locks', 0 RECONFIGURE
```

Then, I restarted the server.

Comment: run [`DBCC MEMORYSTATUS`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907877) and attach the output.

Comment: @Remus I appreciate it, I will check it now. I could remove the index but I am getting the same LOCK error when sending a simple query to the table. Any clues? Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow the [How to troubleshoot SQL Server lock related problems and errors](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2199576) steps.

- make sure [`locks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190253.aspx) option is 0, see [Keep the Locks Configuration Option Default Value](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb402936.aspx)
- make sure lock escalation disabling trace flags are not in place, see [Lock Escalation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286.aspx)
- check your memory consumption, run `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS`, see [How to use the DBCC MEMORYSTATUS command to monitor memory usage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907877)
- make sure you do not have open transactions with many locks, see [`sys.dm_tran_locks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx) and [`sys.dm_tran_database_transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186957.aspx)

There are millions of tables with clustered indexes out there that do not run into lock exhaustion issues. There is something more at play here.

Comment: @Remus I really appreciate your help. It was actually #1, and I will post an answer on how I could solve it. Many thanks again.